# Equivalent hashcat commands for a openssl-enc command?

Tags: aes, md5

This is to find the passphrase for a block cipher. A test generated cipher can be decrypted using

```
$ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in filename
```

which prompts via th console for the password.

I've read openssl-enc man page, and decoded each options. I am confused about MD5 hash function in the encryption and decryption, and the AES algorithm.

I'd like to do the equivalent in hashcat to get the passphrase for this cypher

I know this is not breaking the AES cipher. I must attack the key derivation function, which is MD5.

What hashcat hash mode do I use or how do I do a brute force attack to try many passwords on this cipher with its KDF with hashcat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you need to be aware of here is that this is not a simple "brute-force MD5" operation. Instead, the general brute-force process would have to be:

1. Generate input "password"
2. Run "password" through the OpenSSL KDF (in the MD5 salted-hash form, it's a [modified PKCS#5 PBKDF1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html)), to get the AES key and IV
3. Attempt to decrypt AES data
4. Check if the decryption is successful (!!!)

The most significant problem we run into here is #4. Simply, **there is no reliable way to know for sure whether an arbitrary openssl-enc decryption was successful** - it can find a key it *thinks* is correct but the actual data you get out is rubbish. OpenSSL does not explicitly store any validation data; instead, it [relies on the padding of the final block being in a valid format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding.html#NOTES). This leaves the very bare-bones validation up to chance, absent any further information about the expected decrypted data.

> Although the decryption operation can produce an error if padding is enabled, it is not a strong test that the input data or key is correct. A random block has better than 1 in 256 chance of being of the correct format and problems with the input data earlier on will not produce a final decrypt error.

That said, there is an [open request](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2111) to add such support to hashcat. [One plugin](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2111#issuecomment-608680156) is available. Note that to use this **you must provide a known header of the decrypted data**, as that is what is used to check if the guessed key is correct.

For example, the known header of a ZIP file is `PK`. The known header of an SQLite database is `SQLite format 3.`. Arbitrary text files have no obvious known header (...good luck?). etc., etc..